# Separate key/value pair in multiline JSON read with filebeat and input into logstash

Tags: json, logstash, filebeat

I have a large JSON file I'm trying to input into elastic with logstash and filebeat. In the example I don't care about "results" or "types" but I want all of the "keys" to have the associated "values"

Filebeat Config

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
  - C:\path\to\file
  tags: ["myfile"]
  multiline.type: pattern
  multiline.pattern: '\['
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
```

Logstash Config

```
input {
  beats{
    port => "5044"
  }
}
filter {
  if "myfile" in [tags] {
    json {
      source => "message"
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "filebeat-%{YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Sample JSON

```
{
  "results": {
    "type1": {
      "key1": [
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3"
       ],
      "key2": [
        "value4",
        "value5"
       ]
    },
    "type2": {
      "key3": [
        "value6",
        "value7"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: So I think the answer involves grok. At the moment I'm struggling with how each line is interpreted after it is turned into a single line from filebeat. Also, I'm getting truncated, and losing a lot of the data because it is a giant 50k+ like json file.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => "%{GREEDYDATA:results}(?<keys>key?\"\:\ \[)%{GREEDYDATA:values}
}}
```

Comment: What I have done in the past for a similar thing where we had a not known length of events was ingesting the event, going through pipeline 1 with an exec output going to a python script which allowed me doing foreach stuff and using hexlify (which was not present in the ruby filter for how it had to be done and instelling gems was not an option) and then sending it to another input/pipeline. If you could do it in ruby i guess you can keep it all in the same pipeline without going out of logstash itself